# Schedulable Apex Class to update fields in Lookup record

Tags: apex, class, lookup, scheduled-apex, update

I have a Custom (Managed) object called Individual Email Result (et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c) which contains a Lookup field to a Contact record (et4ae5__Contact__c) and I want to create a schedulable Apex Class to execute daily and update all of the related Contact records (with specific data from the fields of the Individual Email Result record) when it detects that a particular Individual Email Result checkbox (MC_ANY_Sent__c) equals 'true'.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
    public class MCANYSent implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    public void execute( SchedulableContext context )
    {
        Database.executeBatch( this );
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start( Database.BatchableContext context )
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator
        (   'SELECT Id, MC_ANY_Sent__c, et4ae5__DateSent__c, Name, et4ae5__FromName__c, et4ae5__FromAddress__c, et4ae5__Contact__c'
        +   'FROM et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c'
        +   'WHERE MC_ANY_Sent__c = true'
        );
    }

    public void execute( Database.BatchableContext context, List<et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c> individualemailresults )
    {
        for ( et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c ier : individualemailresults )
        {
            ier.et4ae5__Contact__r.MC_Date_of_Last_ANY_Sent__c = ier.et4ae5__DateSent__c;
            ier.et4ae5__Contact__r.MC_Last_Email_Title__c = ier.Name;
            ier.et4ae5__Contact__r.MC_Last_Email_Sender__c = ier.et4ae5__FromName__c + '(' + ier.et4ae5__FromAddress__c + ')';
        }
        update individualemailresults.et4ae5__Contact__c;
    }

    public void finish( Database.BatchableContext context )
    {
        // nothing to do here
    }
}
```

However, when I try to save this, I am getting the following error;
Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: et4ae5__Contact__c at line 25 column 39

Line 25 is the 'update individualemailresults.et4ae5__Contact__c;' line.

I don't need to update the Individual Email Result record, as it isn't being changed, so I'm only looking to update the Contact record in the Lookup field (et4ae5__Contact__c), where all of the changes have been made.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access et4ae5__Contact__c  field of et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c  object on the list hence you are facing this issue.
You cannot update related parent records by updating child list.

Updated code -

```
    public class MCANYSent implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    public void execute( SchedulableContext context )
    {
        Database.executeBatch( this );
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start( Database.BatchableContext context )
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator
        (   'SELECT Id, MC_ANY_Sent__c, et4ae5__DateSent__c, Name, et4ae5__FromName__c, et4ae5__FromAddress__c, et4ae5__Contact__c'
        +   ' FROM et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c'
        +   ' WHERE MC_ANY_Sent__c = true'
        );
    }

    public void execute( Database.BatchableContext context, List<et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c> individualemailresults )
    {
        Set<Id> contactIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        List<Contact> contactsList = new List<Contact>();
        for ( et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c ier : individualemailresults )
        {
            if(!contactIdSet.contains(ier.et4ae5__Contact__r.Id)) {
                contactIdSet.add(ier.et4ae5__Contact__r.Id);
                Contact con  = new Contact();
                con.Id = ier.et4ae5__Contact__r.Id;
                con.MC_Date_of_Last_ANY_Sent__c = ier.et4ae5__DateSent__c;
                con.MC_Last_Email_Title__c = ier.Name;
                con.MC_Last_Email_Sender__c = ier.et4ae5__FromName__c + '(' + ier.et4ae5__FromAddress__c + ')';
                contactsList.add(con);
            }

        }
        update contactsList;
    }

    public void finish( Database.BatchableContext context )
    {
        // nothing to do here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Amit. It saved okay (except that I had to add a ';' after contactsList.add(con), however, I scheduled it to run last night, and none of the Contact records were updated, although, I didn't receive any errors either. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry... just noticed the following error in the Apex Jobs monitoring.
23/12/2019 2:00 PM Batch Apex Failed First error: unexpected token: MC_ANY_Sent__c

Comment: Add space before FROM  and WHERE in dynamic query in start method. See updated answer.